# Pull all images from a folder and create Bootstrap carousel/slideshow

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, twitter-bootstrap-3, bootstrap-carousel

M getting stuck with this code, where i am trying to pull all images inside a folder & put them in list or div, to create Bootstrap Carousel.

```
  <div id="spa_gallery" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel"> 
    <!-- Carousel indicators -->

    <!-- Wrapper for carousel items -->
    <div class="carousel-inner">


<?php
$dirname = "spa_gallery/";
$images = glob($dirname."*.jpg");
foreach($images as $image) {
$imagelist.= '<li class="item"><a href=""><img src="'.$image.'" /></a>      </li>';
}
?>


    <!-- Carousel controls --> 
    <a class="carousel-control left" href="#spa_gallery" data-slide="prev">        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-left"></span> </a> 
<a class="carousel-control right" href="#spa_gallery" data-slide="next"> <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right"></span> </a> 
</div>
</div>
```

where previous code was:

```
<div class="carousel-inner">
  <div class="item active"> <img src="spa_gallery/01.jpg"  alt="First Slide"> 
</div>
  <div class="item"> <img src="spa_gallery/02.jpg" alt="Second Slide"> </div>
  <div class="item"> <img src="spa_gallery/03.jpg" alt="Third Slide"> </div>
  <div class="item"> <img src="spa_gallery/04.jpg" alt="Fourth Slide"> </div>
  <div class="item"> <img src="spa_gallery/05.jpg" alt="Fifth Slide"> </div>
</div>
```

Comment: What is happening when you run your code? What are you expecting to happen?

Comment: Do you echo $imagelist at some place?

Answer (score 0):

try to use

```
<?php
$dirname = "spa_gallery/";
$images = glob($dirname."*.jpg");
foreach($images as $image) {
  ?>
   <div class="item"><img src="<?php echo $image; ?>" /></div>
  <?php
}
```

or

```
<?php
$dirname = "spa_gallery/";
$images = glob($dirname."*.jpg");
foreach($images as $image) {
  $imagelist.= '<div class="item"><img src="'.$image.'" /></div>';
}
echo $imagelist; //<<<<<
?>
```

for me I used something like the next code

```
        $dir_imgs   = "spa_gallery";
        $files_imgs = scandir($dir_imgs);
        foreach ($files_imgs as $key_imgs => $value_imgs){
            $php_imgs = explode(".", $value_imgs);
            $php_imgs = end($php_imgs);
            if ($php_imgs == "jpg"){    
                ?>
                <div class="item"><img src="<?php echo $dir_imgs.'/'.$value_imgs; ?>" /></div>
                <?php       
            }
        }
```

to add class active to img

```
$class_active = 0;  // before foreach

<div class="item <?php  echo (($class_active == 0)? 'active' : '') ?>">
```

then

```
$class_active = 1;
```

so your code will be

```
<?php
$class_active = true;
$dirname = "spa_gallery/";
$images = glob($dirname."*.jpg");
foreach($images as $image) {
  ?>
   <div class="item <?php if($class_active == true){ echo 'active' ; $class_active = false} ?>"><img src="<?php echo $dirname.$image; ?>" /></div>
  <?php
}
```

Comment: How to add class="item active" for any image, to begin slideshow ?               <div class="item active"><img src="spa_gallery/01.jpg" /></div>. So that slideshow starts with this image ?

Comment: Means code goes like this : <div class="item active"><img src="spa_gallery/01.jpg" /></div>  <div class="item">.......

Comment: Bootstrap requires this 1st element to have class="active" , to begin slideshow

Comment: @luna.romania I got your point I updated my answer .. but you can let me know each script you use from my answer and I will modify it to you

Comment: Not working :  <?php
$dirname = "spa_gallery/";
$images = glob($dirname."*.jpg");
$class_active = 0;  // before foreach

  
foreach($images as $image) {
  ?>
  
  <div class="item <?php  echo (($class_active == 0)? 'active' : '') ?>"><a href=""><img src="<?php echo $image; ?>" /></a></div> 
  <?  $class_active = 1; ?>
   
  <?php
}
 ?>

Comment: what is needed is that: suppose i have 10 images, so any 1 is used in "item active" & rest 9 in "item"